# sklearn ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples [192, 48]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, svm, forecasting

I try to make a time series forecasting using svm regression with sklearn. Everything is going well when i train the model using only one feature/variable of the data. but i got this error message while trying to train the model using more than one feature. below is my code. any suggestion to fix this  problem?

```
train=data[0:48]
X_train = train.iloc[:,1:5].values
y_train = train.iloc[:,5:6].values

parameter = {'kernel':['rbf'], 'C':[5],'gamma': [1]} 
scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
svr_rbf = GridSearchCV(SVR(epsilon = 0.01), parameter, cv = 10, scoring=scorer)
svr_rbf.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1),y_train.ravel())
```

Comment: Why you reshape the `X_train` when fitting? Here is the problem. You don't have to do it.

Comment: thank you very much mr alex, your advice really works. I'm adding the .reshape and .ravel because I got error message when fitting with only one of my data feature. I dont really know the reason, i'm new in python and data science, I just searched it on stackoverflow for the solution and i found in some discussion that adding those two make it work.